# Static constructor in static class does not have a return type but get error "method must have a return type"

Tags: c#

I think I'm not understanding static constuctors properly because I get the error "Method must have a return type" for `DutLog`, but it is a static constructor and therfore it shouldnt have a return type?

```
static public class DutLog
{

    static public String m_var1;

    static Dutlog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DutLog() - constructor");
        m_var1 = "hello";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo. The class is named `DutLog`, whilst the constructor is named `Dutlog` (note the lowercase `l`), so the latter is being treated as a method instead.